# Restrict access for Integration user on Business Unit in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there a way i can restrict the API Integration user to have access only to specific Business Units?

I turned off the integration (Enable Integration option) for the Business unit i do not want to access via the API. Even after this i am able to do the Integration with the Business Unit. Is there something that i am missing?

Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am handling this within my application using whitelisting of the Business Units